# React navbar link ActiveClassName not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a navbar with five nav links, but when clicked, it does not redirect to the link or position on the website.

**This is my code for the header:**

```
const Header = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState("nav_menu")
  const [icon, setIcon] = useState("nav_toggler")
  const navToggle = () => {
    if (active === "nav_menu") {
      setActive("nav_menu nav_active")
    } else setActive("nav_menu")

    if (icon === "nav_toggler") {
      setIcon("nav_toggler")
    } else setIcon("nav_toggler")
  }
  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <div className='headerContainer flexSB'>
          <div className='logo'>
            <img src='./images/my_logo.png' alt='' />
          </div>
          <nav>
            <ul className={active}>
              <li>
                <a href='/'>Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href='/'>About</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href='/'>Portfolio</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href='/'>News</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href='/'>Contact</a>
              </li>
              <button className='outline-btn'>BUY NOW</button>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <div onClick={navToggle} className={icon}>
            <i className='fas fa-bars'></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </>
  )
}

export default Header
```

It just stays on the website and refreshes when I try to navigate through the links.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Your a-tags are all pointing to "/", therefore it's not surprising that the same page is always loaded. Set the href-attribute correctly, then it should work. But you should use <Link>-tags (import from "react-router-dom" as in Nazrul Chowdhury's answer suggested) instead of <a>-tags.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the anchor tags from your navigation menu.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

<li>
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
</li>
```

Comment: It shows white screen only

Comment: what url is on the browser for your 'white screen' ?

Comment: I'm using http://localhost:3000/ and after changing the a href='/'>Home/a> to Link to="/">Home/Link>, all that appears is a white screen.

Comment: when you get a white screen, what is your url? is it  localhost:3000 then a / ? i meant is it   localhost:3000/   ??

Comment: Yes only that localhost:3000

Comment: When I restore it to its former state, everything functions flawlessly, except the nav link is broken.

Comment: okay so it is working and now you are in your home page. "localhost:3000 /" is your home page url. you just need to render your home page component for this url. study this link to understand how routing works in react. https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_router.asp

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna navigate page in reactjs , you need install react-router-dom .

and you dont need  tag in reactjs , after insstal react-router-dom

use   .

this npm for react-router-dom  :

```
npm i react-router-dom
```

react-router-dom doc :

https://reactrouter.com/en/main

sampel :

in App.jsx first import :

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
```

then use them like this :

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route element={<Home/>} path="/"></Route>
                    <Route element={<About />} path="/about"></Route>
                    <Route element={<Page404 />} path="*"></Route>
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    );
}
```

in element set your component in path set your address you want be navigate

if you want set home page address :

```
   <Route element={<Home/>} path="/"></Route>
```

if you want create 404 page set this :

```
<Route element={<Page404 />} path="*"></Route>
```

in Header Componet :

import Link :

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
         <Link to="/about">
         </Link>
        </li>
</nav>
```